# installation-like form dialog box

Tags: android, dialog

I've got problem with dialog box. I'd like to do installation-like form that asks question to type / choose option. At this moment did simple dialog box that shows layout with spinner. Any ideas what should I do to create new dialog box on "Next" button (or maybe somehow change layout of current dialog box?) that asks next question?

Picture:

[image]

My code:

```
public class Dialog_box extends SherlockDialogFragment
 {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null));
        builder
               .setTitle("Question I")
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.next, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                   }
               });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Implement a function that creates a dialog and receives an `int` with question number

```
createDialog(int questionNumber)
```

in this function you can have a `switch-case` for the title and content, and after the `switch` set the next button to call

```
dismiss();
createDialog(++questionNumber);
```

This will close the current one, and construct the next one.

The first one you can call from a different button using `createDialog(0);`

Also, at the very beginning of this method, you should check if this is the last one, assuming you have 5 dialogs:

```
MAX_DIALOGS = 5;

if (questionNumber >= MAX_DIALOGS) {
    return;
}
```

You still have to code every dialog, but there's no getting around it.